# How to convert beam dataframe back to PCollection?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-beam

[The flow of the transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjJNz.jpg)

The code snippet given below is working fine and is giving expected results.

```
table_pcollection = (p | 'Read table' >> io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=f'{TABLE_PREFIX}.test_table'))

# Requirement is to keep only some columns from tables
df_table = to_dataframe(table_pcollection, proxy=pandas.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col3', 'col8', 'is_active']), label=f'CNV: To dataframe')


test_pcoll = (to_pcollection(df_table, label='to pcollcetion final pcollection', yield_elements='pandas', include_indexes=True))
test_pcoll | 'Output of test_pcoll' >> io.WriteToText('output/test_pcoll.txt')
```

Now if we apply some operations on the dataframe like, [where/groupby/drop]. It is not working

```
table_pcollection = (p | 'Read table' >> io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=f'{TABLE_PREFIX}.test_table'))

df_table = to_dataframe(table_pcollection, proxy=pandas.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col3', 'col8', 'is_active']), label=f'CNV: To dataframe')

df_table.where((df_table['is_active']) & (df_table['col3'] == 'new'), inplace=True)
df_table.dropna(inplace=True)

test_pcoll = (to_pcollection(df_table, label='to pcollcetion final pcollection', yield_elements='pandas', include_indexes=True))
test_pcoll | 'Output of test_pcoll' >> io.WriteToText('output/test_pcoll.txt')
```

**It is throwing this error**

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'eq' [while running 'to pcollcetion final pcollection/[ComputedExpression[get_column_Series_4878315232], ComputedExpression[get_column_Series_4878353168], ComputedExpression[eq_Series_4878353600], ComputedExpression[__and___Series_4879336496]]:4879347568/FlatMap(evaluate)/FlatMap(evaluate)']
```

*Note: If I use one more transformation i.e., beam.Select([set schema]) before converting PCollection to dataframe, to get dataframe object then I'm able to apply all the operations to dataframe object. And I am able to get PCollection back.

Comment: I've not worked with pandas in conjunction with beam. Does `to_dataframe` convert the types of the column values correctly? `df_table['is_active']` might not be a boolean, but a string?

Comment: Yes values are correct if we don't apply where conditions on dataframe. After applying where conditions I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something we need to clarify in the documentation. The `proxy` argument is for a specific use-case - if you have a `PCollection[pd.DataFrame]` (i.e. the elements are already DataFrames) that you want to convert to a Beam DataFrame - then you can specify the proxy to describe the structure of the DataFrame.

In your case you have an element-wise PCollection, because `ReadFromBigQuery` outputs a `PCollection[dict]` (elements are dictionaries). The appropriate solution, as you found, is to insert a transform that describes the schema of your data like `beam.Select`, and *not* to specify the proxy. The DataFrame API will generate the `proxy` for you based on the schema of the input. There's an example of this in [`apache_beam.examples.dataframe.flight_delays`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/dataframe/flight_delays.py).

Comment: It looks like I already filed https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/21131 for myself to address this documentation gap... I'll prioritize that.

Comment: Specifying schama using ```beam.Select``` that approach we are using as alternative solution. But we are trying for this solution so that we can avoid specifying schema everytime.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately for now you'll need to declare the schema in this way. We are working on adding schema inference for BigQueryIO, which will automate this. You can follow https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/20810 to track this.